# metric spaces notation

Tags: notation, metric-spaces

Can
\begin{equation}
d(x,y) < 5 \end{equation}
be written as \begin{equation} y \in U_5(x)\end{equation} ?

I am curious because I have seen $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ be written as $ y \in U_\epsilon(x)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Where'd the quantifier come from? It should just be $y \in U_{\epsilon}(x)$.

Comment: Yes, ill edit that.

Comment: Yes; $U_{r}(x)$ would mean "ball of radius $r$ around $x$." So $y\in U_{r}(x)$ exactly when $d(x,y) < r$. So this is just two different ways of expressing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the notation that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ implies that $y \in U_{\epsilon}(x)$, your assertion is perfectly valid.  But again, it is notation, so you could use whatever is most convenient to you.  For instance, Rudin uses $N_{r}(x)$.  The notation itself is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your definition of $U_r$ is 
$$U_r(x):=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)<r\}$$
Therefore $y\in U_r(x)$ is equivalent to $d(x,y)<r$. This holds whatever variables (or constants) you insert for $x$, $r$ or $y$.